# How can i set graphics.h to Atom?

Tags: c, atom-editor, mingw-w64, bgi

I'm trying to use graphics.h library in C. I've downloaded mingw, set the path variable, downloaded graphics.h and placed the header files into mingw/include accordingly. I've also set the linkers in Atom.

I did everything i could but i just keep getting this error and can't even compile the code. How can i use graphics.h in Atom to make graphical C applications properly ?

[image]

Comment: What `graphics.h` ? The one from the ancient Borland Turbo C?

Comment: I don't know, i searched for some graphical utulities in C and i came across this library. I'm actually new in C.

Comment: If you are new to C I would suggest to wait with graphics whatsoever and focus on console applications till you gain enough confidence and understanding on how C works. If you want to go with GUI at some point, you better work with modern cross-platform library. Here is an *old* SO post on the subject, yet it is still partially applicable (as in GTK): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450047/how-can-i-do-gui-programming-in-c

Comment: Thanks for your answer. graphics.h is old-dated as i understand. I'll look up for GTK.